# Periodic-Like Holomorphic Function

Tags: complex-analysis

I am reading a paper ([this one](http://repository.ias.ac.in/20407/1/305.pdf)), and the authors (on page 4) implicitly use a result that I do not know. There may be some inaccuracy; I'm inferring the result from the context of the paper.

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function from the upper half-plane in $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ ($f:H \rightarrow \mathbb{C})$. Suppose there is constant $exp(2 \pi i a)$ with $a>0$ real such that $f(z+1)=exp(2 \pi i a)f(z)$. Then, there exists a function $g$ holomorphic near 0 in $H$ such that $f(z)=exp(2 \pi i a z)g(exp(2 \pi i z))$. Proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the function

$$h(z) = f(z)\cdot e^{-2\pi iaz}$$

on the upper half-plane. We have

$$h(z+1) = f(z+1)\cdot e^{-2\pi i a (z+1)} = \bigl(f(z)e^{2\pi i a}\bigr)e^{-2\pi ia}e^{-2\pi i az} = f(z)e^{-2\pi i az} = h(z),$$

i.e. $h$ is periodic with period $1$. Now define $g \colon \mathbb{D}\setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{C}$ by

$$g(w) := h\left(\frac{\log w}{2\pi i}\right).$$

By the periodicity of $h$, the value of $g(w)$ is independent of the choice of the branch of the logarithm, hence $g$ is well-defined. In a small enough neighbourhood of any $w \in \mathbb{D}\setminus\{0\}$, there is a holomorphic branch of the logarithm, hence $g$ is holomorphic.

By construction, we have

$$h(z) = g\left(e^{2\pi i z}\right)$$

and hence

$$f(z) = e^{2\pi i az}g\left(e^{2\pi iz}\right),$$

as desired.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks.